# No puedo ejecutar main de clase java en IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

he importado un proyecto maven con IntelliJ y las clases java me salen con este simbolo y no puedo ejecurar su main[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el icono deberia ser como este    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que significa y como lo puedo solucionar? normalmente me sale con el simbolo de una C, que imagino que es que está compilada.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, tengo entendido que el ícono representa que lenguaje estás usando. Como es java, marca una J. Revisa la configuración de tu IDE si no corre el programa. Si pudieras dar más información del error, sería genial!

Comment: Hola  Rob, bienvenido, realiza el [tour] del sitio, no olvides formular tu pregunta en base a [ask] para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas la solución a tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 5):

Ese símbolo significa que tu IntelliJ Idea no detectó tu código fuente, pero se resuelve muy fácil.

Suponiendo que tienes un proyecto con la estructura normal, es decir, `raizdeproyecto/src/main/java/` y a partir de allí tus paquetes....

1. selecciona la carpeta java y abres un menú contextual.
2. Selecciona `Mark Directory as > Sources Root`

[image: menú contextual]

El icono de tus clases y de la carpeta main debería de cambiar inmediatamente y se te deberían de habilitar los iconos en el editor para ejecutar tu clase tanto a nivel de clase como en su método `main`.